# Обращение с ресурсами в канвасе

Tags: canvas, javascript, html5

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой в канвасе - после загрузки ресурсов весь лист нужно заново перерисовывать.

Вопрос в том, какие есть практики обращения с загружаемыми ресурсами в канвасе? Есть стартовый набор ресурсов, и надо после загрузки всех отрисовать холст.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел сам:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-loader/